# Pandas - Selecting multiple rows at given distances

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

So I have a pandas dataframe which looks something like this:

```
2016-01-28 00:00:00   int   int   int   int   int
2016-01-28 01:00:00   int   int   int   int   int
2016-01-28 02:00:00   int   int   int   int   int
```

The First column is my index column. It has more than 500 rows FYI. So, I need to get:

- The row whose index is `2016-04-04 00:00:00`
- The row right before that row
- The second row before that row,
- The 24th row before row with that said index

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How about you post some example code? What did you try so far?

Comment: Did you try using `.loc` ?

Comment: i tried loc function (working in jupyter), but dont Know how to implement it. I did **my_dataframe.loc['2016-04-04 00:00:00']**, but after that didnt know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it, I'll first generate a test dataset:

```
import numpy as np

# Generating a fake dataset
date_index = pd.date_range('2016-01-28' ,'2018-01-28', freq='h')
random_data = np.random.rand(date_index.shape[0], 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(random_data, date_index, columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])

print(df.head(4).to_string())
#                            A         B         C         D         E
#2016-01-28 00:00:00  0.904552  0.962807  0.349137  0.490480  0.706348
#2016-01-28 01:00:00  0.150306  0.027296  0.810233  0.318828  0.756861
#2016-01-28 02:00:00  0.024970  0.138997  0.403566  0.759649  0.619711
#2016-01-28 03:00:00  0.048545  0.581297  0.395148  0.398693  0.013036
```

With this, we can access values directly with `loc`:

```
# Accessing 2016-04-04 00:00:00
df.loc['2016-04-04 00:00:00']
#A    0.202226
#B    0.921532
#C    0.530494
#D    0.177240
#E    0.324215
```

There are multiple ways to get the requested rows. One of them is:

```
# Accessing positional index of 2016-04-04 00:00:00
d_current = df.index.get_loc('2016-04-04 00:00:00') # = 1608

# Accessing all the requested rows using `iloc`
d_prev = d_current - 1
d_prev_2 = d_current - 21
d_24h_before = d_current - 24 

df.iloc[d_current]
#A    0.202226
#B    0.921532
#C    0.530494
#D    0.177240
#E    0.324215

df.iloc[d_24h_before]
#A    0.458015
#B    0.572196
#C    0.416302
#D    0.445843
#E    0.130110
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this well using `pd.Timedelta` where you would use it like this:

```
selected_date = pd.Timestamp(2016, 4, 4)
one_hour_back = pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
index_one_hour_back = selected_date - one_hour_back

row_one_hour_back = df.loc[index_one_hour_back, :]
```

But this means that you have to have calculated that `selected_date` that you're after and are able to create it like this, or already have it as a datetime object or pandas timestamp.